# Check current or previous audio category iOS

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudiosession

I have an application with multiple `AudioSession`'s and their own `aduioRouteChangeCallback`'s. I need a way of seeing what the current or previous Audio Category was in order to display the proper message to the user.

Does anyone know a way this can be done? From what I've seen on the web so far my hopes are not high that this is possible from what I've found on the web. Any help is greatly appreciate because I'm working against a deadline.

Below is an example of one of my audioRouteChangeCallback,

```
- (void) audioRouteChangeListener: (NSNotification*)notification {
    // Initiallize dictionary with notification and grab route change reason
    NSDictionary *interuptionDict = notification.userInfo;
    NSInteger routeChangeReason = [[interuptionDictvalueForKey:
        AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] integerValue];

    NSLog(@"MADE IT: sensorAudioRouteChageListener");

    switch (routeChangeReason) {
        // Sensor inserted
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonNewDeviceAvailable:
            // Start IO communication
            [self startCollecting];


            NSLog(@"Sensor INSERTED");
            break;

        // Sensor removed
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonOldDeviceUnavailable:
            // Stop IO audio unit
            [self stopCollecting];


            NSLog(@"Sensor REMOVED");
            break;

        // Category changed from PlayAndRecord
        case AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonCategoryChange:
            // Stop IO audio unit
            [self stopCollecting];

            NSLog(@"Category CHANGED");
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Blowing it in- audioRouteChangeListener with route change reason: %ld",
                (long)routeChangeReason);
            break;
    }
}
```

The session is initialized in the objects `init` function,

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return nil;

    // Set up AVAudioSession
    self->noiseAudioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success;
    NSError *error;
    success = [self->noiseAudioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
    if (!success) NSLog(@"ERROR initNoiseRecorder: AVAudioSession failed overrideOutputAudio- %@", error);
    success = [self->noiseAudioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
    if (!success) NSLog(@"ERROR initNoiseRecorder: AVAudioSession failed activating- %@", error);

    return self;
}
```